Dynamic Views field handler title?

In this picture Authored on comes from hook_views_data while Created comes from the Views UI itself as "label". The field is called created, the users see Created, authored on is simply not necessary. Where do I override this so it displays Content: Created?
Looking at the HTML source doesn't make me much wiser.

now core/themes/claro/templates/views/views-ui-display-tab-setting.html.twig

but there is no span in the markup.
